# Database Migration to TFS - circular dependency

Tags: sql-server, architecture, tfs

**What we have**

We have 7 databases for all our internal products. Due to tight integration and lack of architecture they have a lot of circular dependencies between each other in stored procedures and functions.

We need to migrate all this jungle to TFS 2012.

**Problem**

After importing databases into Database Projects we get errors - **circular dependencies are not allowed**

Is there a way to import such databases into TFS without rewriting tons of SPs?

Comment: Consolidate into one Database? Otherwise, not really. As you've said, you've created a jungle over time and that's going to hurt more and more.

Comment: Of course, you are right... It's legacy from previous developers in our dept. :) I thought there can be a way to eat the elephant in pieces

Comment: Could you refactor the offending SP's into a new/single database to remove the circular dependencies?

Comment: To be clear - 'a lot' is >200 SP's for each db. I think it would be better to stop development and start refactoring of all this crap to tree dependence

Comment: I think you're right. Sounds like a maintenance nightmare... Good luck! One alternative you might be able to use is to treat these 200+ procedures as external content and manage them separately. You're going to have to refactor them somehow anyway.

Comment: @AndreyVoloshin - if you don't absolutely have to get it into a dbproj, and are looking more to just have it in TFS, you may find RedGate Source Control a bit more flexible - it will integrate with TFS as well.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio allows composite projects and partial projects.  Some docs for 2010 are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd193405%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  Partial projects do allow circular references so that should provide you a solution.